# How to avoid Services.AddScoped for every Use Case I have?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to learn asp.net core (3.1) and clean architecture at the same time. The GitHub repository which I'm using as base is the https://github.com/ivanpaulovich/clean-architecture-manga and it's great.

The approaches used are pretty good and the repo owner answers you about the reasons of each approach.
The problem I found is not about the approach now, but a better resolution.
The [webapi\dependencyinjection\ApplicationExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ivanpaulovich/clean-architecture-manga/blob/master/src/WebApi/DependencyInjection/ApplicationExtensions.cs) class adds a scope for every use case he has:

```
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.CloseAccount.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.CloseAccount>();
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.Deposit.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.Deposit>();
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.GetAccountDetails.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.GetAccountDetails>();
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.GetCustomerDetails.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.GetCustomerDetails>();
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.Register.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.Register>();
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.Withdraw.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.Withdraw>();
        services.AddScoped<Application.Boundaries.Transfer.IUseCase, Application.UseCases.Transfer>();
```

There is any way to make it generic? To resolve the sample code with one line code only and all the use cases created after it will be injected?

Comment: My two cents With reflection I think you can maybe resolve your problem, there is such functionality in automapper it is called scan assemblies.

Comment: Just keep in mind, "explicit is better than implicit", and if you're learning clean code , code readabilty also matter.

Comment: If (as in this case) you have only a single concrete class that implements the particular interface, then yes you can write a method that takes in an interface and walks all classes in your app to find the single (or first) matching one that implements that interface, and binds it. But... what have you really gained by doing this? Clean code is **not** about saving a few lines of code at the expense of readability!

Comment: convention over configuration could be a possibility

Comment: Could you be more clear @Nkosi please?

Comment: @ChristopheDebove thanks for your comments. So, if I have a hundred of use cases the best way is to keep a hundred of services.addscope?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes given that each case has its own interface, then relying on a common base type wont work. If instead a convention is used, say by name `IUseCase`, then all those interfaces can be found via reflection and their derived types can be mapped and registered.

Comment: @Nkosi just to say, don't know if it helps but, every IUseCase of its namespace implements IUseCase from a shared namespace (a common one). I don't know if I'm doing anything else wrong. Tips and thoughts are welcome.

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes well since there is a common base then reflection can be used to find all the derived interfaces and their implementations. From there it is a simple matter of registering them with the service collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly registering dependencies can be seen as a benefit because you won’t get unwanted surprises later at runtime from seemingly “magic” registrations. This is especially true since your convention to register these types appears to be solely based on interface naming or namespaces. I would recommend you to add some stronger identifiers (e.g. common interfaces, or marker interfaces) if you want to utilize a convention-based registration there. Otherwise, it may seem better to list every single DI registration even if that may seem very verbose.

That being said, there are utilities that will help you with convention-based registrations. Of course, you could always write some code using reflection to register such things automatically. There is also this very useful utility package [`Scrutor`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor) that will register types based on conventions for you.

If each of the type only implements a single interface, then you could use the following scan to register the services as scoped services for their interfaces:

```
var type = typeof(Application.UseCases.CloseAccount);
services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssembliesOf(type)
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.InExactNamespaceOf(type))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithScopedLifetime());
```

Comment: Thanks @poke, I guess it's the best answer.

Comment: In [our book](https://mng.bz/BYNl), Mark Seemann and I advise exactly the opposite where we say that a DI Container is mostly useless when used with "Explicit Register" or "Configuration as Code". In that case we argue that [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) is much more suited. DI Containers start to become beneficial when used with "Auto-Registration" and "Convention over Configuration". See section [12.3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-12/section-12-3) for more details.